# Вычислить значение n-ого члена последовательности

Tags: c++, циклы, числовые-последовательности

[image: task]

Дано натуральное число n (n>=4). Получить Un.

Comment: Осталось дописать "И быстро!"...

Comment: И быстро!......

Comment: ну получите четвертый член по формуле. Если четвертый получили, можете получить и пятый и т.д. Затрудняетесь написать простой цикл?

Comment: В задании указано не использовать массивы

Comment: А массивы и не нужны. Зачем вам хранить **все вычисленные** значения, если для очередного достаточно трех предыдущих?

Comment: а каким образом это сделать?

Comment: Писали когда-нибудь фабоначи? Точно так же, только с тремя переменными(и другой формулой, конечно)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
double vn(int n) {
    double v1 = 0, v2 = 0, v3 = 1.5, v4;

    for (int i = 4; i <= n; ++i) {
        v4 = v3 * (i + 1) / (i * i + 1) - v2 * v1;
        v1 = v2;
        v2 = v3;
        v3 = v4;
        }

    return v4;
    }

int main() {
    for (int n = 4; n <= 10; ++n)
        cout << setw(2) << n << ":  " << vn(n) << endl;
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, добрый человек!!!!

Comment: @Даниил Из спасибо шубу не скроишь :) - лучше щелкните на галочке слева.